# Sockets podem ser multilinguagem?

Tags: c, socket

Visto que ***sockets são uma escolha comum para comunicação de alto desempenho entre aplicações de diferentes plataformas***, a minha dúvida é, isso faz deles também multilinguagem?

Trazendo a situação ao meu contexto, qual poderia ser a razão para que um algorítimo servidor desenvolvido em C não comunicasse com um cliente desenvolvido em outra linguagem?

Existe, no caso, alguma configuração especifica no algorítimo servidor para que ele seja capaz de reconhecer apenas requisições de comunicação de clientes desenvolvidos na mesma linguagem?

Desenvolvi o servidor em C [em Linux] e o cliente é um redirecionador serial [em Windows].

Forneço abaixo o algoritmo servidor que estou a utilizar:

### **Servidor.c**

- O código foi testado e funciona com um cliente *(.c)

  ```c
  int main(void)
  {

  int socket_serv, socket_cli; 
  struct sockaddr_in addr_server;

  //Cria o socket servidor
  socket_serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(socket_serv, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));

  if (socket_serv == -1)
  {
      perror ("Nao foi possivel criar o servidor!\n");
      return -1;
  }

  //Prepara a estrutura do endereco do socket servidor
  addr_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.15.15");//INADDR_ANY;
  addr_server.sin_port = htons(2000);

  //Bind
  if (bind (socket_serv, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_server, sizeof(addr_server)) < 0)
  {
      perror ("Falhou o bind no servidor\n");
      return -2;
  }

  //Listen
  listen (socket_serv, 1);

  //Aceita uma conexão de um cliente
  puts ("Aguardando cliente...\n");
  while ( (socket_cli = accept (socket_serv, 0, 0)) )
  {
      puts ("Cliente conectado!\n");
      ....
  }

  return 0;}
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim.

Não importa em qual linguagem uma aplicação que utilize sockets seja escrita, no fim das contas a comunicação é efetuada por drivers no nível de sistema operacional.

Esta pergunta nem faz muito sentido.

UPDATE

Esta linha

```
addr_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.15.15");//INADDR_ANY;
```

poderia ser problemática, porque está limitando o bind apenas a uma interface de rede...o comum é usarmos INADDR_ANY, que está comentado.

Esta linha

```
while ( (socket_cli = accept (socket_serv, 0, 0)) )
```

está errada, porque não está detectando possíveis erros no accept. Embora não seja comum, erros no accept podem acontecer (já vi acontecerem). O correto deveria ser testar se o valor de "socket_cli" é diferente de -1.

Sem mais informações (por exemplo, que erro especificamente acontece ?) é difícil ter ideia do que está acontecendo.

Sugiro fazer um trace com tcpdump ou wireshark e ver se consegue mais informações.

Comment: Eu agradeço a resposta @zentrunix. Você poderia ser gentil em tentar me explicar porque o meu programa servidor não é capaz de reconhecer o cliente que estou utilizando mas sim um cliente desenvolvido na mesma linguagem? Alguma sugestão? Obrigado!

Comment: POr quue provavelmente o seu cliente em outra linguagem não está se comunicando corretamente.
Uma pergunta mais própria do que a que você fez poderia ser: "por qu eesse cliente de socket na linguagem X não consegue se comunicar com esse outro servidor na linguagem Y" - e o código de ambos, claro (um código mínimo que só mostraria a conexão pra quem for responder achar o erro). Concordo que 'saber que é possível' é um pré-requisito pra essa outra pergunta - então sugiro aceitar esta resposta, e criar uma outra pergunta mais completa

Comment: Caio de Paula Silva: como disse o colega @jsbueno, crie um pequeno programa cliente de teste, e se tiver problemas poste aqui o fonte do cliente e o problema que ocorreu

Comment: Eu agradeço. Uma pena eu não ter acesso ao código do redirecionador serial que estou usando como cliente... Me intriga porque ele tem me servido com outro servidor. Mas não a esse.